# GitKraken with TFS 2017

Tags: git, tfs, gitkraken

I have used GitKraken succesfully with TFS 2015. But after upgrading to Tfs 2017 it cannot pull or push. If i use the https endpoint it always try to login to the server. If i use the SSH endpoint it gives me a "Early EOF" exception.

Can anyone help me if i have to configure something on the TFS 2017, so the Kraken can use that endpoint? How can i find out what's the problem with the SSH endpoint? I cannot find anything related in the logs.

Or the GitKraken implementation of git is not compatible with the new TFS 2017 git? Can anyone use these products together?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of GitKraken? Got was updated in 2017...

Comment: I've just updated to 1.9.3 and still no luck.

Comment: Having the same problem in TFS 2017

Comment: As you've probably already figured out this problem is limited to GitKraken, and not with the VS Git integration, Git bash, or SourceTree. Haven't tried with Tower. I've asked GitKraken for an update, will post here if anything comes back

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce your scenario, when clone a git repo from TFS 2015, no issue at all. But when clone a git repo from TFS 2017, GitKraken always ask for login:

[image]

I've also tried `git clone` command from Command Prompt, after type the Username and Password of TFS 2017, it can clone the repo successfully.

It's suggest to contact GitKraken to report this issue.

Comment: Given that the problem still exists in February 2017, methinx they're not overtly interested in fixing this.

Comment: I've issued a pro support request for this because I get a certificate issue.

Comment: february 2018, still a problem ;( whats up guys?

Comment: Still a problem in 04.2023 - I contacted them but they told me they will not fix it, but can refund me if I want.

Answer (score 2):

After some research and a support call to gitkraken it looks like they have a pretty serious issue. If you currently connect with client certificates to tfs you are going to have issues. this is because they have built gitkraken on NodeGit which has a dependency on lib2git. This in turn has an issue with client certificates which is detailed [here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1152#issuecomment-121011502) for the record the response in 2015 (which has not been updated says the following

> The majors browsers do support client certs, but they don't speak Git.
> This is something which is just not supported by libgit2(sharp).
> WinHTTP should support them, so it should be theoretically possible to
> add this functionality on Windows, but it is rather an edge case of
> functionality.

Gitkraken said there was "little we can do" until this is fixed.  We can only hope that since now 2017 can be configured in this major it will no longer be considered edge.

Comment: The way we solved this for the time being was to disable client certificates in iis.

Answer (score 1):

The new version 2.1.0 of GitKraken solve the problem for us; the release notes: https://support.gitkraken.com/release-notes/current

Comment: didn't solve my issue with it needing a certificate or origin, mind you that maybe an entirely different issue :)